# Adding multiple rows of XML to a dataset and then put it in a datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have the following code (C#):

```
FinalXMLString = FinalXMLString + "<row " + xmlString + " />";
                xmlString = "";
                dataList.Clear();


            }

            StringReader streamreader = new System.IO.StringReader(FinalXMLString);
            XmlTextReader xmlreader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(streamreader);
            dataSet.ReadXml(xmlreader);
```

My FinalXMLString looks as follows:

```
<row EntryID = \"1\" ManufacturerID = \"59\" Name = \"Conbraco hkhkhklh\" AuditDate = \"2/22/2013 10:22:46 AM\" SqlLogin = \"UNITED-SYSTEMS\\jessical\" Application = \"G5;Desktop;admin\" ChangeType = \"U\"  /><row EntryID = \"2\" ManufacturerID = \"59\" Name = \"Conbraco hkhkhklh\" AuditDate = \"3/18/2013 4:14:21 PM\" SqlLogin = \"uss2012SQL01\" Application = \"G5;Desktop;admin\" ChangeType = \"U\"  />"
```

That is from debugger mode so the backslashes are still there. The problem is that the ReadXml fails every time. Is the format of the xml above not correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a "show string as XML" tool in Visual Studio; that might help you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that xml string you have two root elements. Here is a simplified example of your FinalXmlString:

```
<row />
<row />
```

Try wrapping those elements in a rows element Example:

```
<rows>
  <row />
  <row />
</rows>
```